# fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler. 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\p0io.c'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

When building a c++ solution in Visual Studio 2013, i get this error:

```
fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler. (compiler file: 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\p0io.c')
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Errors related to compiler file `p0io.c` may be caused by locale settings in Windows 10. This may be fixed by *turning off* UTF-8 support in the region settings, as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1033088/is-it-possible-to-set-locale-of-a-windows-application-to-utf-8/1451686#1451686).

Comment: Dude, this bugfix is awesome... and so impossible to find alone.

Comment: Plus, I switched to UTF-8 to be able to write my git commit comments under vim... which didn't work, but at that time, I didn't switch back off to my locale... what a mistake