# VS2013: fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

The code is quite simple:

```
int main(void){
    return 0;
}
```

and the compile error goes:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\userdata\zdck\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project1\project1\source.cpp : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\p0io.c', line 2807)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have no driver F but there comes an error in f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\p0io.c??

Believe in me that I have checked dozens of posts with title "C1001 blah blah..." here and there but no one works for me.

My VS: V2013 Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5
My OS: win 10, 64 bit

[image: snapshot of the error]

Comment: The path to `F:` is probably just from where the compiler was compiled -- that build system probably had the source at the path you see there.  It's telling you where in the compiler the error occurred.

Comment: Builds fine for me with the same version of VS 2013. Try to create a new console project with default settings and type the same code into that. If it builds then you may have some odd project settings, or there is something wrong with the .cpp file itself. If it still doesn't build then it's time to repair/reinstall VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [error C1001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801744/fatal-error-c1001-an-internal-error-has-occurred-in-the-compiler-f-dd-vctool) related to compiler file `p0io.c` is mainly caused by enabling `Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`in `Region Settings`. You could see the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1033088/is-it-possible-to-set-locale-of-a-windows-application-to-utf-8/1451686#1451686) about the concrete reason. You could click `Time &Language -> Region-> Additional date, time, &regional settings-> Region-> Administrative->Change system locale` and turn off `UTF-8`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Kq3.png)

If the error couldn’t be fixed, I suggest that you could update your VS version to VS2019.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I checked, and I don't have UTF-8 turned on.

I'm also fully updated (Version 17.7.4 of Visual Studio)