# How do I fix an "internal error" ("fatal error C1001")?

Tags: visual-c++

[image]

I've read through the answers to a related question ([VS2013: fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077945/vs2013-fatal-error-c1001-an-internal-error-has-occurred-in-the-compiler)) so I know that the 'f:' drive refers to the machine the code was compiled on (my machine has no 'f:' drive).

The project is more than 200,000 lines of code. If the problem is in my code, I need more information than this about where to start.

I've tried deleting all build and output files and rebuilt from scratch.

I've tried rebooting.

I've tried randomly rearranging my most recent code and comments (in response to the vague suggestion to "change the program near the locations listed").

I would love to include a sample of my code that can reproduce the problem. But, as you can see, it doesn't specify what code change on my end might have caused this.

I've a run chkdsk to look for bad sectors and my drive is fine.

(I'm running Version 17.7.4 of Visual Studio on Windows 10) (Dell Precision 3660 with 32.0 GB of RAM)

Answer (score -1):

Basic debugging:

Can you download compile and run any sample programs?

How long until the error happens? After two seconds or after compiling half your program?

Can you go back to a working version?

Comment: > *Can you back to a working version?*


Yes, but that eliminates all the work we've done. We've started to rewrite all of the functions from scratch that were added since the working version. But so far we still get this error. At this point our wild guesses include the idea that there's an upper limit around 200,000+ lines of code. We've all been working on this product for 20+ years, and we've gotten pretty good at solving errors in our own code. But we don't know how to fix an "internal error" without any clue about the location of the error.

Comment: *> How long until the error happens?*

As shown in the screen shot, it happens at the very end of the compiling process. All of the source files are successfully compiled. It then sits at 'Generating code' for a few minutes (as it has always done when compiling the release version) and then gives this error and fails.

Comment: *> Can you download compile and run any sample programs?* Yes. Every other project in the company compiles without errors. Every other configuration of this project compiles without errors. This error is only happening when trying to compile the release version of the product.