# Error when getting started Actix-web: failed to run custom build command for `brotli-sys v0.3.2`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, actix-web

When I did build my first actix-web test I found below error:
**error: failed to run custom build command for `brotli-sys v0.3.2`**

How to solve?

My system properties:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363
System Type x64-based PC
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 6.00 GB
```

Terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\dev\rust_Lab\hello-world-actix> cargo run  
   Compiling cfg-if v0.1.10
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
   Compiling futures-core v0.3.5
   Compiling slab v0.4.2
   Compiling futures-sink v0.3.5
   Compiling winapi v0.2.8
   Compiling bytes v0.5.6
   Compiling once_cell v1.4.1
   Compiling iovec v0.1.4
   Compiling pin-project-lite v0.1.7
   Compiling futures-io v0.3.5
   Compiling pin-utils v0.1.0
   Compiling smallvec v1.4.2
   Compiling scopeguard v1.1.0
   Compiling matches v0.1.8
   Compiling tinyvec v0.3.4
   Compiling copyless v0.1.5
   Compiling adler v0.2.3
   Compiling itoa v0.4.6
   Compiling percent-encoding v2.1.0
   Compiling either v1.6.1
   Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.9
   Compiling gimli v0.22.0
   Compiling fnv v1.0.7
   Compiling match_cfg v0.1.0
   Compiling rustc-demangle v0.1.16
   Compiling object v0.20.0
   Compiling quick-error v1.2.3
   Compiling widestring v0.4.2
   Compiling linked-hash-map v0.5.3
   Compiling regex-syntax v0.6.18
   Compiling hashbrown v0.9.0
   Compiling cpuid-bool v0.1.2
   Compiling dtoa v0.4.6
   Compiling opaque-debug v0.3.0
   Compiling base64 v0.12.3
   Compiling mio-uds v0.6.8
   Compiling mime v0.3.16
   Compiling language-tags v0.2.2
   Compiling instant v0.1.7
   Compiling tracing-core v0.1.16
   Compiling thread_local v1.0.1
   Compiling futures-channel v0.3.5
   Compiling futures-task v0.3.5
   Compiling bytestring v0.1.5
   Compiling lock_api v0.4.1
   Compiling unicode-bidi v0.3.4
   Compiling unicode-normalization v0.1.13
   Compiling http v0.2.1
   Compiling lru-cache v0.1.2
   Compiling addr2line v0.13.0
   Compiling winapi v0.3.9
   Compiling memchr v2.3.3
   Compiling log v0.4.11
   Compiling libc v0.2.77
   Compiling proc-macro-nested v0.1.6
   Compiling bitflags v1.2.1
   Compiling getrandom v0.1.15
   Compiling typenum v1.12.0
   Compiling idna v0.2.0
   Compiling brotli-sys v0.3.2
error: failed to run custom build command for `brotli-sys v0.3.2`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\Administrator\dev\rust_Lab\hello-world-actix\target\debug\build\brotli-sys-c17dbe422e853792\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:include=C:\Users\Administrator\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\brotli-sys-0.3.2\brotli/include
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  running: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\amd64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-Z7" "-Brepro" "-I" "brotli/include" "-FoC:\\Users\\Administrator\\dev\\rust_Lab\\hello-world-actix\\target\\debug\\build\\brotli-sys-924a6a49d6a39ff4\\out\\brotli/common/dictionary.o" "-c" "brotli/common/dictionary.c"
  dictionary.c
  brotli/common/dictionary.c: fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\p0io.c', line 2739)
   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
  exit code: 2

  --- stderr
  fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git


  error occurred: Command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\amd64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-Z7" "-Brepro" "-I" "brotli/include" "-FoC:\\Users\\Administrator\\dev\\rust_Lab\\hello-world-actix\\target\\debug\\build\\brotli-sys-924a6a49d6a39ff4\\out\\brotli/common/dictionary.o" "-c" "brotli/common/dictionary.c" with args "cl.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 2).


warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I did found a solution for this error.

Issue resolved by disable "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" in Region Settings.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/heCud.png]

This hinted as per [fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler. 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\p0io.c'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801744/fatal-error-c1001-an-internal-error-has-occurred-in-the-compiler-f-dd-vctool) , as per https://superuser.com/questions/1033088/is-it-possible-to-set-locale-of-a-windows-application-to-utf-8/1451686#1451686.